# Alfresco Share: what shall I do make my documents previewable?

Tags: alfresco

When I upload document into *Alfresco Share* library - site tells me: "preview is anavailable for a document" though document is a standard winword.

What shall I do to make my winword documents previewable? I use *Community Alfresco Edition*

Comment: What version of alfresco are you using. Did you install via binary installer? If yes did u select openoffice when installing?

Answer (score 4):

In order to let the preview correctly work, you need the following third party software to be [properly installed](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Installing_and_Configuring_Alfresco_Community_Edition_3.2#Alfresco_components) on the server running Alfresco:

- [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org) (NOTE: don't use version 3.3.0 as it is affected by a [known bug](http://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-5747))
- [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)
- [swftools](http://www.swftools.org/)

The first link I provided already includes the configuration changes you need to provide Alfresco with in order to point out to those external tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom preview for documents in alfresco share, Fist you need to add new mime type ([here](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dev-extensions-share-custom-mimetype.html)) in alfresco and then Create your preview plug in which renders the content in document details page

you can refer this example for creating plug in [PdfJs](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/share/src/main/webapp/components/preview/PdfJs.js)

For more information refer [this](https://community.alfresco.com/community/ecm/blog/2011/07/21/custom-web-previews-in-share/) page